# How to get count of opened handles that belongs to a certain process?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, handle, window-handles

You can use the program [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see how many handles running applications have.  Is there a way with Delphi code to get this number?  I am interested in tracking the number for the application itself; not to find the number of handles used by other applications as Process Explorer is doing.

My intention is for the application to track/detect possible resource leaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the [`GetProcessHandleCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This API function is in recent versions of Delphi imported by the **Winapi.Windows** unit (so you can omit the presented one):

```
function GetProcessHandleCount(hProcess: THandle; var pdwHandleCount: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
  external 'kernel32.dll';

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  HandleCount: DWORD;
begin
  if GetProcessHandleCount(GetCurrentProcess, HandleCount) then
    ShowMessage('Handle count: ' + IntToStr(HandleCount));
end;
```

Comment: Works well. I used this to detect resource leaks caused by not calling `Socket.Close()` when a network connection error occurs.